# How to clear local storage after a certain amount of time if user doesn't revisit site?

Tags: local-storage

I store a unique ID in a client's browser's local storage using AmplifyJS so when they revisit the website they can resume their checkout process.

But what if they visit my site once, get the ID stored in local storage, and then never visit the site again? How do I get their browser to automatically delete that local storage data if their browser never touches my site again?

Local storage data doesn't seem to automatically expire.

Comment: Well, that's interesting. I guess there's no way.

Comment: No, I think that you shouldn't care about it. If user is concerned, he will do it by himself. If you don't want to get too old data when your user comes back, add a timestamp to your localStorage so that you can cancel it.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Good to know this useful pattern of doing things.